# IIS Express - increase memory limit

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, iis-express

I have a VS project in .NET MVC5 which loads an external dll file that uses a lot of memory. In average it uses from 500-1000MB memory.

Now when I try to debug my project with default IIS Express server I almost always get OutOfMemory exception.

I know that there is a /3gb flag for normal IIS but what about IIS Express. Are there any settings so I can enable this or is there any other solution to this problem except of installing a full IIS on development PC?

PS: Developer PC has Windows 8.1 64x and Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: You are using 32 or 64 bit OS?

Comment: 64 bit OS.

And I don't have IIS, I got IIS Express only.

Comment: @Gapipro: Have you tried increase virtual memory for the worker process?

Comment: @mrd where can this be set?

Comment: How much memory do you have installed on your computer?

Comment: Pc has 8GB of ram. But process worker has problems when allocating more then 800MB

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Go to Visual Studio - Tools - Options Menu

Choose: - Projects and Solutions, then Web Projects

tick the checkbox: "User the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects"

No Registry edit necessary.

Comment: For me, this resulted in a "Could not load file or assembly. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."

Comment: @JoshNoe one of your dependencies is probably a 32bit version. so you will need to get a 64bit version of that dependency, if that is not possible, you will need to continue working with 32bit version of IIS Express

Answer (score 21):

Both Cassini and IISExpress runs as 32 bit by default... You can configure Visual Studio 2012 to use IIS Express 64-bit by adding/setting the following registry key:

```
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\WebProjects /v Use64BitIISExpress /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

IIS Express 8 and above supports both modes. Best to use an application like process explorer after making the registry change to inspect the IISExpress process and make sure that its running from the 64 bit location. When you install IIS 8.0 Express on a 64-bit system, both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of IIS 8.0 Express will be installed respectively in the "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\IIS Express" and "%ProgramFiles%\IIS Express" folders.

Alternatively, you can install IIS locally and configure it to run your application. You can configure Visual Studio to point to a local instance of IIS.

Comment: The registry value doesn't seem to work in Visual Studio 2010. Is there any equivalent for this in VS 2010?

Comment: For Visual Studio 2013, just change `11.0` to `12.0` in the registry key path

Comment: This registry changed worked for Visual Studio 2015 RC which is `14.0`.

Comment: Restarted VS2015 to take notice of the registry changes in 14.0